# Error while launching the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio, rcurl

I create a VPS for Rstudio and launched an EC2 instance in the following configuration

1. I first chose the AMI (default AMI for free tier users)
2. Then I added the piece of code for setting up the R server  with credentials.
3. I also defined the security protocol with port 8787 for accessing my server.
4. I launched the EC2 instance and had a approval for the status check .
5. I was now able to access the R sever with mycredential.

I tried to read the data n my s3 bucket. 
For this, i tried downloading the RCurl package in R.

I had a error that * Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status*

could someone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Please paste the error that was reported. Likely the Linux user does not have permission to write on the lib directory where R downloads the packages.

Comment: @SanjayMehrotra its solved , thank you